# How can I select a value from a table twice with different values

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have Message table in which "senderid" and "receiverid"exists. 
I have User table in which username of each user is found.

Now I want to make a stored procedure in which I select the username where userid=senderid and username in which userid=receivername.

I tried this but it's wrong, coz I never made something like this before.

```
SELECT       SystemUser.SU_Username Where SystemUser.SU_ID=MessageReciever As RecieverName, SystemUser.SU_Username where Message.SenderID = SystemUser.SU_ID As SenderName FROM            Message CROSS JOIN
                     SystemUser
```

Is there a method to do what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select from the SystemUser table twice, with table aliases:

```
SELECT       SUR.SU_Username  As RecieverName
           , SUS.SU_Username As SenderName 
FROM            Message 
               JOIN SystemUser SUR
                  on (SUR.SU_ID = Message.MessageReciever )
               JOIN SystemUser SUS
                  on (SUS.SU_ID = Message.SenderID )
```

Answer (score 1):

after having looked at your sql for quite some time, i think i figued what you wanted to do:
just join twice

```
select  r.SU_Username as RecieverName,
        s.SU_Username as SenderName
from    Message m
inner join SystemUser r on (r.SU_ID = m.MessageReciever)
inner join SystemUser s on (s.SU_ID = m.SenderID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given something like:

```
create table users ( name text, id integer );
create table messages ( receiver_id integer, sender_id integer );
```

what you are looking for should be:

```
select us.name as sender_name, ur.name as receiver_name
from users us, users ur, messages m
where us.id = m.sender_id and ur.id = m.receiver_id;
```